# How to edit App menu from Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2

I start "QML App with controls" project in Qt Creator. I see that I can add to canvas different kind of controls, but I do not see how I can in graphical mode edit menu like: File, View, Edit... In constructor on canvas it's simple do not exists, but it's exists of running app, like http://img.ctrlv.in/img/15/10/03/560f856edb26c.png

Comment: Seems like the menu is not in the component you are editing with the visual designer. It is likely in the main qml component. Also, I personally would not use the visual designer, it is lame. It a shame recent Qt versions now create projects with QML forms by default. Talk about misguided priorities...

Comment: any alternatives? except manual creation of qml

Comment: Typing it is the best way to get exactly what you want. The visual editor is for chumps who know nothing.

Comment: I mean, ultimately, you can't do programming without programming. Some cultivate a belief the visual editor could make it possible for non-programmers, but as a designer who got into programming, I can tell you - don't bother with the visual editor. Learn how to code, QML is actually very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the [`menu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menu.html) in the `main.qml` file, here is an example application:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Open")
                onTriggered: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Open action triggered"));
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Save")
                onTriggered: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Save action triggered"));
            }
        }
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&Help")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("About")
                onTriggered: messageDialog.show(qsTr("About: test QML app with menu"));
            }
        }
    }

    MainForm {
        anchors.fill: parent
        button1.onClicked: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Button 1 pressed"))
        button2.onClicked: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Button 2 pressed"))
    }

    MessageDialog {
        id: messageDialog
        title: qsTr("Message Test")

        function show(caption) {
            messageDialog.text = caption;
            messageDialog.open();
        }
    }
}
```